# Finding Conditional Density of $V|U$

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

$X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables. Let $U=X$ and $V=cX+Y\sqrt{1-c^2}$, where $c$ is some constant. Find the conditional density of $V|U$.

To find the conditional density, I first find the joint density. I have $f_{U, V}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{v-cu}{\sqrt{1-c^{2}}}\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^{2}}}$ for the joint density with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^{2}}}$ as the Jacobian. To find the marginal density of $U$, I have: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{U,V}\left(u,v\right)dv$. But I do not know how to simplify this expression. Am I on the right track? If so, how do I find the marginal density?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I find the marginal density?

Really? $U=X$ thus $U\sim N(0;1)$

Thus it is immediate to derive that

$$f_{V|U}(v|u)\sim N(cu;1-c^2)$$